# Can't remove reddish tint even after quitting RedShift

Tags: 14.04, redshift

I installed RedShift on my Ubuntu 14.04, and started the redshift application.

It gave my screen a reddish tint.

Howecver, the screen does not revert back to its original color even after I have quit Redshift.

I have tried toggling the icon on the tray,  and also tried 
killall redshift , but nothing works.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

---

Restarting my PC solved the problem !